# Flash AS3 Event Function with Arguments

Tags: actionscript-3, events, dispatch

I need to make a event function that has parameters you pass in, that would look something like this.

```
    public function foo(e:Event, args)
    {
        trace(args[0]);
    }


    addEventListener("fooEvent", foo);
    dispatchEvent(new Event("fooEvent", true), args);
```

Anyway that I could do this? Thanks, guys.

Comment: You would create a custom Event by subclassing Event and adding your custom arguments to that event object. That is the way the event system is designed to be used. :)

Comment: See this link for more help http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_AS3__Creating_and_dispatching_Custom_Events-17609.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package {
  import flash.events.Event;

  public class CustomEvent extends Event {
    public var params:Object;

    public function CustomEvent(type:String, paramsObj:Object = null, bubbles:Boolean = true, cancelable:Boolean = true) {
      super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

      if (paramsObj) {
        params = paramsObj;
      }
    }

    public override function clone():Event{
      return new CustomEvent(type, params, bubbles, cancelable);
    }

    public override function toString():String{
      return formatToString("CustomEvent", "params", "type", "bubbles", "cancelable");
    }
  }
}
```

You can then structure the event like:

```
dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("fooEvent", {param1:"foo", param2:"bar"}))
```

And retrieve the data like:

```
addEventListener("fooEvent", function(event:CustomEvent):void {
  trace("param1: " + event.params.param1);
  trace("param2: " + event.params.param2);
});
```